# Add or change column in NIFI

Tags: apache-nifi

I am new to NIFI and want to add columns to NIFI using updaterecord processor.
[image]

this does not work for some reason.

Here is the error:
[image]

Comment: If you're trying to use Expression Language then Replacement Value Strategy should be `Literal Value`